# bindChildView and bindGroupView same cursor

Tags: android, expandablelistview

using `getChildrenCursor` how to make `bindChildView` receive the same cursor as `bindGroupView`?

```
        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {


            Cursor childCursor = groupCursor;//bd.ReadData("select * from images where _id="+2);


            return childCursor;
        }
```

this way returns the Cursor of all groups and not specific to one Group...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By getting the GroupId was able to query the correct row for each child as below

```
        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {

            int groupPos = groupCursor.getPosition();
            int groupId = groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            Log.d("data","Show data groupPos->" + groupPos + "ID->" + groupId);

            Cursor childCursor = bd.ReadData("select * from images where _id="+groupId);

            return childCursor;

        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to answer the question "how to make bindChildView receive the same cursor as bindGroupView". Possibly the problem you were trying to solve was not the question that you asked (http://xyproblem.info/). Is this Q&A something that could be useful to future readers?